# Browser kills applet

Tags: java, browser, applet, alfresco

I developed an applet and everything is working so far. (embedded in Alfresco).
But when I switch to another page of Alfresco, where applet is not embedded,
then it gets killed by Firefox after some time.

So I wondered if there is a workaround to keep the applet alive, even if it is not embedded in the current page? Otherwise it would be really annoying to the users, because they have to trust the applet each time it starts due to self signing it.

Comment: AFAIK, no. If the user closes the page your applet is on (or navigates away), your applet will be killed.

Comment: do not self sign it then

Comment: As an option, have a frameset, and keep your applet open in a frame of this frameset.

Comment: Have a single page web site

Comment: What does the applet do and why does it need to be embedded in a browser?

Comment: In Alfresco (Content Management System) you have a document library where you can drag and drop files, which are then uploaded. This does not work for E-Mails which you drag and drop from Microsoft Outlook, so what my Applet does is add a space, where you can drag and drop the E-Mails from Microsoft Outlook and then uploads it to the document library. When you click on the E-Mail you get to the document details site (no applet embedded here as you cannot upload documents on this site here). When you go back applet, is initializing and loading again.
I think I won't self sign, thank you all! :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers:
There is a feature called '[draggable' applet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/java6u10-405109.html). A use can drag & drop the applet e.g. on the desktop. Afterwards one is able to leave the page...